# Ubuntu 16.04 Xfce unable to start display setting

Tags: xfce, randr

Within the screen, going to APPLICATIONS -> SETTING then DISPLAY the response is 
Unable to Start the Xfce display settings
This system is using RandR 1.1. For the display settings to work version 1.2 is required at least

Comment: I have a similar issue. Doing `xrandr --version` shows that the program version is `1.5.0`, however, the second line is `Server reports RandR version 1.1`. Just an update and upgrade is not going to work here.

Answer (score 4):

I've been bumping into the same "Unable to start the Xfce Display Settings" popup while `xrandr --version` reports program & server versions 1.5.0 & 1.5, respectively. So this error isn't necessarily related to xrandr versioning.

It appears the presence of any xorg configuration file (`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, or in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`) causes the error during `xfce4-display-settings` startup.

Remove any xorg config files, log-out, log-back-in, and you should be able to access the xfce display settings as intended.

...the catch is, if you *actually need the existing xorg config*, its unclear how to write-out/meld changes applied by xfce settings with your own xorg.conf. For example, I need a second xscreen to exist (display=:0.1), but don't want the xfce desktop doing anything to it.
So this is more of a workaround than a solution...

Answer (score -1):

Since the problem seems to be an outdated RandR, I would try running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to try and update RandR.

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: it's really not as simple as you stated.

Comment: I have a similar issue. Doing `xrandr --version` shows that the program version is `1.5.0`, however, the second line is `Server reports RandR version 1.1`. Just an update and upgrade is not going to work here.